# Git - rm equivalent for "add ."?

Tags: git, git-add, git-rm

If you're using Git from the command line, is there a way to delete in one fell swoop all the files to be deleted in the Changed but not updated list?  Rather than doing manual removes using wildcards.

Comment: Note that `git commit -a` would have all tracked files that were removed also removed in commit.  Just FYI.

Comment: `git commit -a` only adds files—it's what most people, including myself have been using. The answer is `git commit -A`. It will stage items to be added AND stage items for deletion at the same time! See Sujoy's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files shown as deleted in the "Changed but not updated" section of status are deleted from the work tree but not from the index. To stage the deletion in the index (i.e. remove the file from the index) you can do:

```
git diff -z --name-only --diff-filter=D | git update-index --remove -z --stdin
```

`--diff-filter=D` shows only the differences to the index that are deleted files, `--name-only` just prints their name and `-z` uses NUL to separate file names so that you don't have to worry about filenames with embedded newlines. `update-index` then removes the given files from the index.

If you have a version of `xargs` that supports `-0` then you could do the slightly simpler:

```
git diff -z --name-only --diff-filter=D | xargs -0 git rm
```

Answer (score 8):

The following should stage all files, whether deleted or not, in the index:

```
git add -A
```

Comment: This is the quick answer I'm sure everyone is looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the files listed under *Changed but not updated* are already in the index. You can discard their changes by using `git checkout .`
To remove file that are new, but have not been added to the index you can use `git clean`.
But for deleting files that are modified and in the index ... well there is no easy solution, you probably have to use a combination of `git rm` and `git ls-files`.

**EDIT:**
`git ls-files -m` should list the files you are looking for. Combine it with `git rm` and you are done:

```
git-ls files -m | xargs git rm // NOT TESTED
```

**EDIT:**
I probably misunderstood a part of your question. My solution will delete all files listed under *Changed but not updated*. If you want to remove the files listed as *deleted*, you have to use `git diff` as Charles Bailey shows in his answer.

Comment: Thanks.  So how would you combine?  git rm < git ls-file -m?  Not too familiar with bash.

Comment: `git ls-files -m` lists all modified files, not just deleted ones. I don't think that you want to delete all modified files, just the ones deleted from the the work tree.

Comment: @Charles: yes you are right - and that's even how I understood the question. But you are probably right and that is not what the OP wants ... got my +1 for picking that up